# Write extract function in SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, clickhouse

I need to extract `1421412043` from

```
REQ: <<online>true</online><cardno>1421412043</cardno><amount> 349812948:00, OLDID= 1969)
```

I try this, but it gets `1421412043</cardno><amount> 349812948:00, OLDID= 1969)`:

```
SELECT
    extract(value, '.*<cardno>(.*).*') AS cardno
FROM ......
```

How to write that regular expression right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
extract(value, '<cardno>([^<]+)') AS cardno
```

Or,

```sql
extract(value, '<cardno>([0-9]+)') AS cardno
```

As per the [`extract`](http://extract(haystack,%20pattern)%C2%B6) reference, "*it takes the fragment that matches the first subpattern.* Here, `([^<]+)` is a capturing group that matches one or more chars other than `<` (and `([0-9]+)` matches and captures one or more digits).